# how to convert a coordinate (x,y) to a unique value

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

how to convert a elliptic point to a unique value?

ie using ECC for curve y2=x3+x+1 and p=23 i generated elliptic points and for a message, I mapped the characters of the message to elliptic points so computed.

Now i want to pass the set of points to another cryptographic algorithm say goldwasser inorder to perform encryption.

Is there any algorithm to convert the point to a integral value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Elliptic Curve Point Compression.

In OpenSSL(which follows X9.62 standard), there are [functions](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EC_POINT_new.html) for this purpose:

- BIGNUM *EC_POINT_point2bn() - convert EC point to bignum
- char *EC_POINT_point2hex() - convert EC point to hex string

And ofcourse, functions to convert it back:

- EC_POINT *EC_POINT_bn2point()
- EC_POINT *EC_POINT_hex2point()

For JAVA, check out the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936171/how-do-i-compress-or-encode-the-elliptic-curve-public-key-and-put-it-over-the-ne).